# Store multiple types of data from file

Tags: c, file, extract, store

Can someone help me with the following request:

I have a file with only one line that contains the following groups separated by a space

- real numbers
- integer numbers
- hexadecimal numbers
- the character 'N'

Here are some examples:

```
    0 0.3 -1 +3 0xc 'N'

    2.12211 1 -100 'N' 0xac 'N'
```

Basically the first line might contain real numbers,integer numbers,hexadecimal numbers, the character 'N' and each group is separated by a space

Is there any way to create a vector of multiple types(in C,not in C++) that will contain the elements separated by spaces(also the hexadecimal numbers should be converted to decimal numbers?

For the first example it shall be

```
 V[0]=0
 V[1]=0.3
 V[2]=-1
 V[3]=3
 V[4]=12
 v[5]='N'
```

For the second example it shall be

```
V[0]=2.12211   
V[1]=1
V[2]=-100
V[3]=3
V[4]='N'
v[5]=172
V[6]='N'
```

Comment: just because you want something "not in C++" doesnt make the C++ tag relevant

Answer (score 2):

Rule #1: Avoid premature optimization.

Define a type of your data:

```
enum data_type {
    data_type_integer = 0,
    data_type_float,
    data_type_char,
    ...
};
```

Now define structure to contain these data:

```
struct data {
    enum data_type data_type;
    int data_integer;
    float data_float;
    char data_char;
};
```

Of course this wastes some space, but unless you write a db engine or something, remember rule #1. If it really bothers you, pack the data (not `data_type`) into union. But if you make a mistake with union, it will bite you (as the compiler cannot check that, for example, you stored `char` and read `int`).

Now you have a single type to store various data types.

To parse it, there are various approaches. I suggest to read each item as a string and then parse the string using sscanf. The reason for this two-step approach is that you can check the string contents to determine the type: If it contains 'N', it's 'N'. If it contains 'e', 'E' or '.' it is float, etc.

Comment: If we combine your structure and Code-Apprentice's union, then that should be the optimal solution to this problem..right?

Comment: @AmberBeriwal yes; but this looks like a beginner question, and I advice against using unions by beginners (they bite).

Comment: Thank you.
But how exactly should i parse the content of .txt file with that format?

My idea was to have one big array of chars and store each element from file that is separated by space.
And the using the ASCII code i would transform the characters to numbers and add it in a vector of doubles but i wasnt successful with this
Can you post an actual example of parsing from this format of .txt file as you think?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to create a vector of multiple types(in C,not in C++)

This seems like a good use of a union. You can define it as

```
union data {
    float f;
    int i;
    char n;
};
```

Now declare an array of unions:

```
union data V[20];
```

And populate it like so:

```
 V[0].i=0
 V[1].f=0.3
 V[2].i=-1
 V[3].i=3
 V[4].i=12
 v[5].n='N'
```

In the parsing logic, you will need to decide which field of the union to use in order to ensure the correct value is stored as you intend.

Comment: Create a structure that contains a tag and the union. The tag can be an enumeration that describes what is in the union.

Comment: Thank you.
But how exactly should i parse the content of .txt file with that format?

My idea was to have one big array of chars and store each element from file that is separated by space.
And the using the ASCII code i would transform the characters to numbers and add it in a vector of doubles but i wasnt successful with this
Can you post an actual example of parsing from this format of .txt file as you think?